# no executable found matching command "dotnet-aspnet-codegeneration" in my new MacBook Pro

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

In my new MacBook Pro, while trying out visual studio code and dotnet core, I created an asp.net razor page application. While scaffolding, I am getting error.
my dotnetcore version is 2.1 `netcoreapp2.1`
In my first `<ItemGroup>` I have three PackageReference :-

1. `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`
2. `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />`
3. `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" />`

I tried the command `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` and I get the error. I tried `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" />` in new `<ItemGroup>` but still I am getting the error `no executable found matching command "dotnet-aspnet-codegeneration"`
I tried same thing in my windows laptop and there it is working fine.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your .csproj file, inside of ItemGroup:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
```

Also make sure you have it installed it.
This is how it should look:

```
 <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="2.1.0" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
```